# Plotly Labels Overlap in Shiny R. Tried Changing the Size of Points, Label Text, and the Plot, but the Problem Persists

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I have Plotly R code in a Shiny App. The plot is difficult to read, however, because of overlapping labels. I've tried to make the labels more legible by changing the size of points, the size of the label text, and the size of the plot, but I just can't find a good solution -- even if ggrepel was supported by Plotly, it loads extremely slowly, so may not be realistic for my application.

This is how one of my plots looks:

[image]

This is my code:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = out, 
        x = ~decade, 
        y = ~similarity,
        mode = "markers+text",
        text = ~word,
        type = "scatter",
        marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                      size = 15,
                      line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                                  width = 1.5)),
        height=650) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autotick = F,
                      tickmode = "array", 
                      tickvals = c(1800, 1810, 1820, 1830, 1840, 1850, 1860, 1870, 1880, 1890),
                      dtick = 10,
                      range = c(1790, 1900))) %>%
           config(displayModeBar = F)
```

This is the data to create the above plot:

```
out <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        similarity = c(0.996772282427112,
                       0.996515764525304,0.995689089393821,0.992812701242555,
                       0.990496665717053,0.989877469983925,0.986781130786658,
                       0.986182081799632,0.985576881762976,0.98553877862653,
                       0.985237647827682,0.984296095696392,0.983137627205533,
                       0.982555753886872,0.981172906094605,0.997359893764231,
                       0.995272221249232,0.991836900052964,0.991202287549529,
                       0.990409016613532,0.989246082232041,0.988249600118526,
                       0.987087332198701,0.987037451917099,0.985642471178718,
                       0.985377872954079,0.985259818231651,0.981725549242432,
                       0.981451955380812,0.979591471408517,0.986404424904908,
                       0.986395565011384,0.986049026348,0.983709463477862,
                       0.983105926789153,0.975701868827438,0.973989122221292,
                       0.973375747413249,0.973057848030701,0.972554700495868,0.97249078374025,
                       0.969594830747254,0.967242481994034,0.962636342744457,
                       0.96041737383578,0.996089055648307,0.992100905547774,
                       0.99124396362403,0.99049465550967,0.989109447933839,
                       0.988732958575935,0.98799809294292,0.986784433071627,
                       0.985154228055813,0.983861712400814,0.983110009468682,
                       0.983031902369918,0.979690672557612,0.979165977683873,
                       0.977560230711916,0.993461030398511,0.992861828638606,
                       0.990081888907396,0.989059435629085,0.98867096907959,
                       0.987011701495913,0.985460959363828,0.984817274932796,
                       0.984726368811773,0.984722517608915,0.984465124431817,
                       0.982958104141771,0.977175821220029,0.968601889468798,
                       0.968051750410802,0.996893438643129,0.996857627996838,
                       0.993561114117784,0.993369724266977,0.991518582471627,
                       0.990424774010035,0.988711509794145,0.988564484660703,
                       0.988448506241278,0.987175346960377,0.986419269197933,
                       0.984417219977097,0.983537778526245,0.98349637593341,
                       0.983462338945331,0.993882091303283,0.991934611782163,
                       0.990169455252365,0.988111982642104,0.986820926103001,
                       0.986762754555676,0.984725234108437,0.983264966278013,
                       0.980190969868634,0.977625286453419,0.973897070475416,
                       0.973501462326639,0.97171034524675,0.970519555981155,
                       0.966457175802219,0.997775515349102,0.997106162884176,
                       0.996124554577213,0.994565550501663,0.992739865246229,
                       0.992544309669314,0.99218216366121,0.991692738451479,
                       0.991274123712083,0.99091520023484,0.988619877903374,
                       0.98846227738369,0.988135031790969,0.986797982968646,
                       0.98437299748619,0.995971763443977,0.994631140699691,
                       0.989776745761784,0.989393302044834,0.986139621955008,
                       0.986096640726177,0.985208089620084,0.982616665263083,
                       0.979105793515647,0.978823577697907,0.975977976936024,
                       0.975969274820177,0.975107014081505,0.975046272279794,
                       0.973661981104633,0.997346358641136,0.996852210183219,
                       0.995315374306627,0.995243492386844,0.994642466888664,
                       0.993552326365786,0.993477843156452,0.993289427857091,
                       0.99313640359108,0.992275880449453,0.990967920829264,
                       0.9891744859104,0.988714162659605,0.986393379884814,
                       0.986358102090102),
              word = c("standard","industry",
                       "divisions","ruinous","riot","odious","thirty","hazard",
                       "desperate","contemptible","president","barley",
                       "injure","taught","expensive","precious","comparatively",
                       "facilities","grievous","metals","hence","fluctuation",
                       "decline","abundant","attributable","fluctuations",
                       "raw","rapid","heavily","lotteries","detriment",
                       "abundant","abundance","metals","accumulated","suddenly",
                       "precious","remunerating","decline","comparatively",
                       "com","meal","accrue","advancing","burdens",
                       "deficient","pauperism","churchmen","denomination","rome",
                       "scarcity","ease","abundance","idleness","comfortable",
                       "crops","fluctuation","seasons","scanty","starvation",
                       "abundant","flourishing","rapid","agriculturist",
                       "season","steady","stimulus","ruinous","depressed",
                       "consume","drive","deficient","consumers","abundance",
                       "cattle","cessation","grudge","occupations","losses",
                       "ruined","speculation","tobacco","fortunes",
                       "deficiencies","plenty","abundance","disease","ruinous",
                       "depressed","grow","advancing","extravagance","bushels",
                       "wasting","steadily","abundant","losing","gigantic",
                       "prospective","depression","flourishing","lapse",
                       "metric","wasteful","comparative","scarcity","lavish",
                       "wrecks","buoyancy","wounded","krupp","bred","torpedo",
                       "drilling","breeding","woollen","coolie","stocks",
                       "inch","voyages","seasons","onerous","struggling",
                       "swept","habits","losses","accrue","ruined","blood",
                       "start","demoralizing","drive","imposing",
                       "substitution","losing","settlor","energies","ameliorate",
                       "lightening","peril","luxury","parted","immensely",
                       "declining","capabilities","lighten","amelioration",
                       "congestion","brewer","alleviation"),
            decade = c(1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,
                       1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,1800L,
                       1800L,1800L,1800L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,
                       1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,1810L,
                       1810L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,
                       1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,1820L,
                       1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,
                       1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1830L,1840L,
                       1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,
                       1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1840L,1850L,1850L,1850L,
                       1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,
                       1850L,1850L,1850L,1850L,1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,
                       1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,1860L,
                       1860L,1860L,1860L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,
                       1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,1870L,
                       1870L,1870L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,
                       1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,1880L,
                       1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,
                       1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L,1890L)
)
```

Help is very appreciated!!!

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4674) regarding plotly.js

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't understand the solution proposed. Some links here take me to D3-Labeler (https://github.com/tinker10/D3-Labeler) for fixing this problem, but D3-Labeler is for JavaScript. I don't see an R implementation, and I do not know enough JS to integrate D3-Labeler into my Shiny App.

Comment: I would accept unofficial suggestions about changing annotations or adapting the D3 code...